# dnu restore is not recognized though I did dnvm upgrade

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dnx

I have Visual Studio 2015 update1 installed and did a dnvm upgrade sucessfully.

Still dnu restore is not recognized, what should I do ?

Comment: please include the output of `dnvm list` and `dnvm version`. Verify the content of `%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\runtimes`. Examine the PATH. If `dnvm` is not installed then use `@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "&{$Branch='dev';iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.ps1'))}"` and then execute `dnvm upgrade -r coreclr` and `dnvm upgrade -r clr`. See [the documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html)

Comment: do you have a whitespace in the user name?